# UserDefaults with Struct - TableView not displaying data saved from UserDefaults?

Tags: swift, tableview, userdefaults

I am having a problem displaying data on the table view cell below is the code.

This is my struct where I have first and last set up.

```
struct Person: Codable {
        var firstName: String
        var lastName: String
 }
```

This is the view controller where I am saving the data.

```
class viewController: UIViewController {
        
   var newPerson = [Person]()
        
   override func viewDidLoad() {
          
     let person = [Person(firstName: "Peterson", lastName: "Jota") , Person(firstName: "John", lastName: "Paul")]
          
       let encoder = JSONEncoder()
          if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(person) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "savedPerson")
          }
        }
      }
```

This is where I am trying to load the data

```
class SeconClass: UITableViewController { 

    var person = [Person]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

     tableView.delegate = self
     tableView.dataSource = self

    if let savedPerson = defaults.object(forKey: "one")  as? Data {
      let decoder = JSONDecoder()
      if let loadedOne = try? decoder.decode(Person.self, from: savedPerson) {
        self.person = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "savedPerson")
         }
       }
    }

 func tableView( tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return  person.count
      }
      
 func tableView( tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellID", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = person[indexPath.row]
        
        return cell
      } 
}
```

Comment: you should at least explain something to make us understand what's the problem and the situation.
and also, make sure your code is inside ` `
so it's highlighted as a code and easier for us to read

Comment: How you retrieving persons data from userDefault, plz add code

Comment: Have you set the `dataSource` of your `tableView`? You are not using `UITableViewController` and your tableView dataSource methods are outside your `viewController` class

Comment: Yes, I did all that. the problem is I cant display person data in table view cell

Comment: call `tableView.reloadData()` after decoding the data.

Answer (score 1):

First of all don't use `UserDefaults` to pass data between controllers. This is very bad practice.

The errors are pretty clear:

- You are encoding an array but decoding a single object.
- You are using different keys in `UserDefaults` which don't match.

I recommend to use a custom struct for all keys. This avoids mismatches because code completion will help you

```
struct Key {
    static let savedPeople = "savedPeople"
}
```

and name classes with starting uppercase letter and use a less confusing name for the array (`people`)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
        
   var people = [Person]()
        
   override func viewDidLoad() {
          
     people = [Person(firstName: "Peterson", lastName: "Jota") , Person(firstName: "John", lastName: "Paul")]
          
     let encoder = JSONEncoder()
     if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(people) {
         UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: Key.savedPeople)
     }
  }
}
```

In the second view controller `catch` a potential error and there is `data(forKey` in `UserDefaults`. And in `UITableViewController` `dataSource` and `delegate` are connected by default.

```
class SeconClass: UITableViewController { 

    var people = [Person]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

       // tableView.delegate = self
       // tableView.dataSource = self

       if let personData = defaults.data(forKey: Key.savedPeople) {
       do {
           self.people = try JSONDecoder().decode([Person].self, from: personData) {
       } catch {
           print(error)
       }
   }

...
```

Answer (score -1):

Checkout this ,It works for me...

```
var dataArray = [String]()
    
    //Save the data...
    
    dataArray.append(ChatID)
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(dataArray, forKey: "ChatIDArray")
    
    //Retrive the data...
    if let chatdataArr = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "ChatIDArray") as? [String] {
        let trueCount  = chatdataArr.filter { $0 == chatID }.count
        print(trueCount)
        if trueCount == 0 {
            cell.Countlblref.isHidden = true
        }else {
            cell.Countlblref.isHidden = false
        }
        cell.Countlblref.text = "\(trueCount)"
    }
```